# How to compare experimental data with teorethical prediction

Tags: statistics, approximation, regression

I would like to know, what is the method to approximate experimental data to teorethical one.

I have heard about polynomial regression. After calculating particular matrices and solving set of linear equations I am getting the polynomial coefficients which approximates the best these set of data.
My question is though, how can I compare that experimental data to acquired polynomial. Should I calculate the particular values for each x value as it has been labeled to starting data and then plot them?

Comment: Is there a theoretical model ?

Comment: This question is not clear. Is there a theory as to what the coefficient on each polynomial coefficient should be? What is it you want to test?